# Exocortex FFT not working

Tags: c#, dll, fft

I'm trying to use Exocortex library and when I use FFT, I get this long error and I don't know what am I doing wrong.
The error:
[image]

And my code:

```
        float[] array = mySamples;
        List<float> arrayList = array.ToList();
        while (!IsPowerOfTwo(arrayList.Count))
        {
                arrayList.Add(0);
        }
        ComplexF[] complexData = arrayList.Select(p => new ComplexF((float)p,0.0f)).ToArray();
        Fourier.FFT(complexData, FourierDirection.Forward);
```